# How to Use Jquery Smart Wizard with some ajax pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, smart-wizard

I am having difficulty in understanding how to use the jQuery smart wizard.

I have managed to get it going with static html for my first three tabs but I now want to add another tab which uses an ajax call to get the data based on the data I have collected in the previous tabs.

I know there are callback functions for leaving and entering steps but the documentation is unclear on how to use them (or it maybe I don't understand enough jQuery/JavaScript to correctly interpret the documentation)

The way I read it is I would use

```
$("#smartwizard").on("stepContent", function(e, anchorObject, stepIndex, stepDirection) {
   // if this is the correct step index then
   // do my ajax call using a promise 
   // (Which I do not understand fully how to do. 
   // I have never used a promise before.)
   // and return my html. (Where is the html going to be put? is it the 'tabpanel'?)
   return myHTMLfromtheajaxcall;
  // else do nothing
  // How do I stop it overriding the existing content?
  // Do I return '' or false or what?
});
```

What and where do the parameters for the function come from. What is 'e'? What is 'anchorObject'? The other parameters are self explanatory.

I hope somebody can explain things in simple terms with some examples.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is the complete documentation http://techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard#ajax_contents

Comment: The documentation does not explain anything in simpler terms about what I am asking about. That is why I am asking this question. The part about ajax contents is confusing. I am new to the idea of promises which I am just learning about having never heard of them before this. A more concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: Reading the documentation and I am confused about what the 'loader' is?
What element is "'anchorObject the jQuery object of the selected step'" referring to?
What is 'e' that is passed?

Comment: When I do an ajax call I normally do a post then use 'success'
   ` $.ajax({
        url: "./ajax/LoadFabric.php", 
        method: "POST", //Fetching method
        data: { ColourId: DataArr[id], Outer: true },
        success: function(data) //If data fetched successfully from the server, execute this function
            {
                $('#OuterFabricSelect').html(data);
                $(".tab-content").height("100%");
                $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("fixHeight");
            }
    }); `

Comment: How do I convert that to a promise?

Comment: I have managed to get promises working after much trial and error.
Basically I discovered if you dont want to do anything the just return false. That is not mentioned anywhere as far as I could see.

Comment: My solution works on a switch statement on the step number and then returning a promise for the content to display

Comment: e.g.
       case 6: // Confirmation
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./ajax/Load_Step-6.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        ShoeId: gShoeId,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        resolve(data)
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        reject(error)
                    },
                })
            });
            break;